# Emulate the view pages using visual force

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

Anyone know how to emulate this using visualforce? Is there some sort of global variable commands to get the icon? or am i forced to cssing this all? I am just looking to get the top portion where the contact and contact.Name is. Thanks been trying to make a VF page that looks identical to the ones that salesforce provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the title and subtitle (in your example, "Contact" and "CT-0000000001"), use `apex:sectionHeader`.  To get the icon and coloring, use the corresponding standardController on the page (in conjunction with `apex:sectionHeader`), putting any custom controller logic in a controller extension.  For example:

```
<apex:page standardController='Contact' title='Contact - {!contact.name}'>
     <apex:sectionHeader title='Contact' subtitle='{!contact.name}'>
         <!-- you can add additional header content here if needed, for example, the 
              top-of-page help text on the Convert Lead page -->
     </apex:sectionHeader>
     <apex:form>
         <!-- rest of your page logic -->
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: To get the icon and the coloring you can also explicitly set the `tabStyle` attribute on the page tag with the name of the object whose look you're trying to mimic, which will set the CSS to match that object's look and feel. `<apex:page tabStyle="Contact">`